# styled-components css`` returns unexpected output when called inside a function - leading and trailing comma and interpolates code instead of values

Tags: styled-components, prettier, css-in-js, tagged-templates

**EDIT: Actually I was wrong, the first example also doesn't work! It also interpolates the code!!**

---

I'm experimenting with [styled-components css prop api](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#css-prop) and I ran into the following problem:

This code works well:

```js
const myCss = css<PropsWithTheme>`
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: ${props => props.theme.color};
`

const MyComponent = () => <div css={myCss.toString()} />
```

But the following does not:

```js
const getCss = (color: strinbg) => css<PropsWithTheme>`
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: ${color}; // I tried injecting the color directly
  color: ${() => color}; // And also returning it from a callback inside the css``, just as I would access props/theme
`

const MyComponent = () => <div css={getCss('red').toString()} />
```

The output css here is `width: 100px; height: 100px; color: ,red,; ,() => color,;`, which is obviously not valid.

Using template string interpolation to stringify the output solves the problem, but results in very bad readability due to Prettier enforcing this format:

```js
const MyComponent = () => (
  <div
    css={`
      ${getCss('red')}
    `}
  />
)
```

Unfortunately moving the inerpolation anywhere outside the css prop definition ( in component body or creating a stringify function) breaks the functionality (either prop/theme access, all css doesn't get applied at all).

It seems to be related to this issue: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1641, but the suggested solution there is to use the `css` helper function, which I'm already doing :(

Is there an easy fix to my problem?